# redirecting echo with undefined variable

Tags: solaris, ksh, flags

I'm running a script in solaris 11 with different results depending of the shell used.

The script has an echo redirecting to a file given by an environment value:

```
echo "STARTING EXEC" >> $FILE
```

ps. EXEC is just the message the script show, it's not using `exec` command.

If I execute the script without the variable FILE defined (using `/usr/bin/ksh`):

```
./start.sh[10]: : cannot open
```

and the script continue the execution.

The flags for ksh are:

```
echo $-

imsuBGEl
```

But if I change to `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`, the script show me the echo in stdout and there is no error shown.

The flags for xpg4 sh are:

```
echo $-

imsu
```

I tried to change the flags with `set +-` (I can't remove El flags, but BG are removed ok), but can't get the same behavior.

Is there anything I can do to get the same result using ksh without `cannot open error`?

```
/usr/bin/ksh --version

version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u 2011-02-08
```

I'll want the script keep going, showing the message in stdout, instead of showing the error just like it does now.

Like shellter said in the comments, the good thing to do is to check if the FILE variable is defined before doing anything. This is a script `migration` from an `HPUX` to a `SOLARIS` environment, and client think they must have the same result as before (we unset FILE variable before execution to test it).

Comment: `${FILE:?_Var_FILE_NOT_SET}` might help. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comment shellter. The problem is that there is not only one script, there are more than one thousand (my fault, I don't explain very well before, sorry), and I don't know if I am allow to change them.

Comment: Ah, 1000s of files to modify, that makes a difference ;-) ... Lets go back to basics. I don't quite understand your `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh, the script show me the echo in stdout and there is no error.`. So you see `STARTING EXEC`? Yes? AND in ks93, does the script stop at that point or is is just the error message `./start.sh[10]: : cannot open` .  Does the script continute to run anyway? Please edit your question to tell us 'I want the script to stop' OR 'I want the script to keep going'. Finally, as the msg mentions EXEC, are you using the shell command `exec`. If so, please include the exact cmd

Comment: Please edit your question with this info, rather that responding in comments. We try go get good questions so we can write good answers. Having to read thru a long thread in comments with bad formatting won't help your chances of getting help and a solution to your problem. Use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box to format code, data and system responses. Highlight a block of msgs, code, etc, with your mouse, then click on `{}`. Good luck.

Comment: Also, I looked for definitions of `-E` and `-I` on kornshell.com and only found a definition for `-E`. Becuase that option reads other setup files and sources them, that could contain a hidden problem. But as you say it works with `xpg4/sh` I guess that's not a sure bet either. Can't you just make sure FILE gets set. That seems like a bug. I always want my log files present and correct ;-)! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter. I think the good method is to check the variables before execution always, as you said. I'll try to talk with the client to find a solution this week and update the information with it. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running Solaris 11, not Solaris 64.

Should you want to have your scripts to work under Solaris 11 without having to search everywhere the bogus redirections, you can simply replace all shebangs (first line) by `#!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution we are going to take is to `install the ksh88 package` and use it like default shell (`/usr/sunos/bin/ksh`). This shell have the same behavior the client had before, and we can let the scripts with no modifications.

The ksh used in solaris 11 is the 93 (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E24456/userenv-1.html#shell-1)

Thanks @jlliagre and @shellter for your help.